# Flutter CallBack Function

Tags: android, function, flutter, dart, callback

I have a quantity that needs to be updated in the parent widget. Quantity needs to be updated when pressing + or - Icon in the child widget. I passed the callback function the the child stateless widget, but it is not working. Instead I get an error saying setstate() or markneedsbuild() called during build.

This is the parent widget

```
class Wash extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WashState createState() => _WashState();
}

class _WashState extends State<Wash> {
   int quantity = 0;

   void updateQuantity(command) {
     if (command == 'add') {
       setState(() {
        quantity++;
       });
     } else {
      setState(() {
       quantity--;
     });
    }  
   }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
    body: OrderTile(
          imgPath: 'shorts',
          itemType: 'Shorts',
          quantityCallBack: updateQuantity,
        ),
   );
 }
```

This is the child widget

```
class OrderTile extends StatelessWidget {
OrderTile({this.itemType, this.imgPath, this.quantityCallBack});

final String imgPath;
final String itemType;
final Function quantityCallBack;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        flex: 1,
        child: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/${imgPath}.jpg'),
          radius: 30.0,
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        flex: 3,
        child: _Description(
          title: itemType,
        ),
      ),
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: quantityCallBack('add'),
        child: Icon(
          Icons.add,
          size: 24.0,
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: 14,
      ),
      Text('1'),
      SizedBox(
        width: 14,
      ),
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: quantityCallBack('remove'),
        child: Icon(
          Icons.remove,
          size: 24.0,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
}
```

Am I doing the right thing for the function call back implementation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're calling your callback function in the wrong way inside your `onTap` callback. Change:

```
onTap: quantityCallBack('add'),
```

for

```
onTap: () => quantityCallBack('add'),
```

You can only pass a function the way you passed if they have the same type. In this case the `onTap` is `void function()` it doesn't have any arguments.

Also, your not passing the updated `quantity` value to your `Text Widget`